# complex series expansion of a particular form

Tags: sequences-and-series

Write down an expansion of the form:

$\sum  c_nz^n$

Given:

$f= (1+iz)/(1-iz)$

Simplify and summation:

$ = (1+2iz -z^2)/(1+z^2)$

$ = \sum  (-1)^n (z)^{2n}  (1+2iz-z^2)$

$ = \sum  (-1)^n [z^{2n} + 2iz^{2n+1} - z^{2n+2}]$

Am i doing this right? 
It seems that i'm missing something.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Comment: put $ around a few of your math expressions :)

Comment: @Timbuc could you help me out now? :) ty

Comment: @Arashium could you help me out now? :) ty

Comment: What is limit on $|z|$ ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}=-1+\frac2{1-iz}=-1+2\sum_{k=0}^\infty i^n z^n\;,\;\;\text{for}\;\;|z|<1$$

Comment: +1 looks so simple. but difficult to end up doing step1 to step 2. does that mean that my calculation would end up with this simplification?

Comment: @rebc  I can't say what would you end up with. Please do pay attention to the fact that the above is valid **only** for $\;|z|<1\;$ , i.e. inside the unit circle.